# ERROR when trying to Create projects in openstack (Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password )

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

[Openstack | Keystone](https://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-obs/keystone-users.html)

I follow above official Openstack documentation to `Create projects, users, and roles`, I met this error message:

```
strong textMissing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
```

I already tried these commands:

```
$ export | grep OS_

$ declare -x OS_AUTH_URL="http://controller:35357/v3"
```

And it still did not work, I think it's related to the `OS_auth_url`

Comment: First, why do you try to use such an old release? It's end-of-life for a couple of years now. I'm not sure I understand your `declare`command, but why not just `export OS_AUTH_URL="http://controller:35357/v3"`? But again, try a new release.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define other  OS variable like:

```
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=iQds9Glj6QH4
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://openstack.local:35357/v3
export OS_INTERFACE=internal
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
export OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
export OS_AUTH_PLUGIN=password123
```